# Problem with if else statement

Tags: php, mysql

Somehow, my code is executing both the `if` and the `else` code!

```
$q = "SELECT id FROM ".TBL_VOTECOUNT." WHERE voteid = '$mainid' AND voterid = '$_SESSION[id]'";
$result = $database->query($q);
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

}
else {

}
```

The code for `$database->query` is

```
function query($query){
   return mysql_query($query, $this->connection);
}
```

Is there any reason why this code should run both the `if` and `else` blocks?

Comment: There is nothing happening in your if else?

Comment: One word answer: no!  Could you be running the block of code twice with different TBL_COTECOUNTs?

Comment: No. There is no reason for that. Please show your real code, and the results that lead you to believe that both are executed.

Comment: That's not the problematic code. Post (copy and paste) the real code.

Comment: unless you are experiencing the schrodinger's quantum "cat" state, executing both branches at eh same time is not possible in this universe!!

Comment: I think the possibility of PHP executing if and else at the same time is less likely than an error in your code. How do you know that both are executed? Do you just feel that both are executed or is the above code enough for you (Maybe you have some hidden code...)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How can you tell that it is executing both? The code itself does not seem to have a problem. 
I suggest trying the following

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  echo ":-)";
}
else {
  echo ":-(";
}
```

Do you get a happy face,  an unhappy face or both?

Comment: Haha, you should teach programming to kindergarden kids, +1

Comment: Haha that would give me both faces! But in all seriousness, it's giving me both. It can't be running twice!

Comment: @Luke You say "that *would* give me both faces." Are you reluctant to try it for some reason? Surely it would only take a second?

Comment: It did give me 2 faces, but I solved it now. Was looking at a different query!

Comment: @luke Please, enlighten us.. so you were executing 2 queries? one yielded true and the other false, that must be it?

Answer (score 0):

```
$query  = "SELECT id FROM ".TBL_VOTECOUNT." WHERE voteid = '$mainid' AND voterid = '$_SESSION[id]'";      
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

list($id) = mysql_fetch_array($result);

if(empty($id))
{
    echo "No Results :| ";
}else{
    echo $id ; //Echo's the ID
}
```